# WPF inkcanvas background image resize

Tags: c#, wpf, image, inkcanvas

[before i add label on ink canvas image look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oO5DN.png)

```
  elhard = new Ellipse();
  elhard.Height = 5;
  elhard.Width = 5;
  elhard.Fill = Brushes.DarkOrange;
  InkCanvas.SetLeft(elhard, Mouse.GetPosition(inkcanvas).X);
  InkCanvas.SetTop(elhard, Mouse.GetPosition(inkcanvas).Y);
  inkcanvas.Children.Add(elhard);  

    lblhard = new System.Windows.Controls.Label();                 
    lblhard.FontSize = 25;
    lblhard.Content = hard_tisue[hardinc];   

                    lblhard.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.DarkMagenta);
                    InkCanvas.SetLeft(lblhard, Mouse.GetPosition(inkcanvas).X);
                    InkCanvas.SetTop(lblhard, Mouse.GetPosition(inkcanvas).Y);

                    inkcanvas.Children.Add(lblhard);
```

//this is my xml

```
                <InkCanvas x:Name="inkcanvas" ResizeEnabled="False"   EditingModeInverted="None"  Cursor="Pen" MouseMove="inkcanvas_MouseMove" MouseDown="inkcanvas_MouseDown" MouseRightButtonDown="inkcanvas_MouseRightButtonDown" MouseLeave="inkcanvas_MouseLeave" MoveEnabled="False"  UseLayoutRounding="False" ClipToBounds="False" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" >
                    <InkCanvas.Background  >
                        <ImageBrush Stretch="None"  />
                    </InkCanvas.Background>



                </InkCanvas>

            <!--<Image Name="inkcanvas_image" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=border}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth,ElementName=border}"  Stretch="Fill" Margin="1,1,1,1"  />-->

        </Border>
```

[this is how background image in ink canvas moves to left side how to prevent image from moving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnMLE.png)

Comment: Can you tell me where you have added the `Label` here and whats your actual goal.

Comment: hear the character in second pic is label . I add them on mousedown event when i add them image resize to right side i want to stop that image to resize .

Comment: Any solution for this ??

Comment: You have to frame the question correctly.  What you have mentioned here can be understand by you alone but not others.  Pls frame it clearly.

Comment: I have inkcanvas . which contains image in background . when i add label on canvas image in background moves to right side . i want to stop that image from moving .

Comment: you understand my problem ???

Comment: Show me the code of adding the `Label`.  Also, Update the question with the details. .

Comment: anyone know the answer please

Comment: Provided details is not enough for us to resolve your issue.  If possible, create a fresh sample WPF app and show us the scenario and all code.